# Better expression for down-casting and up-casting?

Tags: oop, inheritance, downcast, upcasting

If you know the difference between **upcasting** and **downcasting**, then you
still can get it wrong because you can only make an educated guess about how
the inventor of these names paints his inheritance trees.

In computing science trees grow into the ground most of the time or from left to right, hence
you know that **downcasting** probably means a cast to the more specialized type
but having a wording that forces you to do such a guess is awful.

Is there a more reasonable terminology for these concepts?

Answer (score 0):

Glad I asked, so I can vent my anger 8-).

Yes there are much clearer and impossible to confuse words for this:  **specializing-cast** and **generalizing-cast**.

Please do not use the words **upcast** and **downcast** ever again!